# Pile Django update query into one big query instead of looping queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to get this into one big update query instead of looping over the queryset?

```
foos = Foo.objects.all()

for f in foos:
  f.bar = Bar.objects.filter(created__lt=f.foo_field)).first()
  f.save()
```

I have tried this which I thought might work but unfortunately it throws a FieldError:

```
Foo.objects.all().update(bar=Bar.objects.filter(created__lt=F('foo_field')).first())
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do things that complex in an update. You would need to use a third party package to run bulk update, so your for loop is probably the best option.

Comment: post the models and explain what needs to be updated